# How to detect @mentions in Kotlin using regex?

Tags: android, regex, kotlin

I need help in matching the @mentions words which itself contains some ids which will be used to redirect users to particular userId.

Here is my string:

```
val string = "Hello @[%user%]Akash(ef54321). Is @[%user%]Shubham(45321gg) there with you?"
```

> I need parsed response == "Hello @Akash. Is @Shubham there with you?"

Also onClick of @Akash And @Shubham I need ids which are there in format (xxxxx).And @mentions should appear in grey background.Any help would be highly appreciated.Thanks,
I am using

```
val string = "Hello @[%user%]Akash(54321).Is @[%user%]Shubham(543215) there with you "
val matcher = Pattern.compile("^[@]\\w+|(?<=\\s)[@]\\w+").matcher(string)
while (matcher.find()) {
     println("TAG"+matcher.group())
}
```

Comment: Can you share your current code/efforts? With expected vs current output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
val string = "Hello @[%user%]Akash(ef54321). Is @[%user%]Shubham(45321gg) there with you?"
val rx = Regex("""@\[%user%](\w+)\((\w+)\)""")
val res = string.replace(rx, "@$1")
println(res)   // => Hello @Akash. Is @Shubham there with yo?
val users =rx.findAll(string).map{it.groups[1]!!.value}.toList()
val ids =rx.findAll(string).map{it.groups[2]!!.value}.toList()
println(users) // => [Akash, Shubham]
println(ids)   // => [ef54321, 45321gg]
```

See the [Kotlin demo](https://rextester.com/AERMU91626).

The `@\[%user%](\w+)\((\w+)\)` regex contains two capturing groups  for users and for IDs. In the replacement method, you may refer to those values using `$1` and `$2` placeholders.

**Pattern details**

- `@\[%user%]` - a `@[%user%]` literal string
- `(\w+)` - Capturing group 1 (user, `$1`): one or more letters, digits or underscores
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `(\w+)` - Capturing group 2 (ID, `$2`): one or more letters, digits or underscores
- `\)` - a `)` char.

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor. It really helped me a lot and saved my time.